# What is IP of Blade and Soul Euro server?

Tags: blade-and-soul

Unfortunately, I'm not sure is this question an offtopic or not.

At the moment of 3 Closed Beta Test there are a lot of rumors about where actually the Euro server of Blade & Soul is located. Developers officially declared that the server is physically located in Frankfurt, but I could not find the actual IP address anywhere. I do not care where the server is physically located, the IP address I need to study delays and setup programs that improve the connection accordingly.

According to the data that I have seen in the network performance window of Performance Monitor (WIN10), the client connects to a range of IP addresses, some of which are in America, some in Korea. In addition, a list of connected addresses change from time to time that does not allow me to understand what kind of address is the actual address of the Euro server.

Official forum and Dojo forum did not give me an answer to my question.
Does anybody knows actual IP for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer in BnS Dojo by Rapture:

> 206.127.149.3:10100 EU Soha game sub-server hosted in Frankfurt, Germany
>
> 206.127.149.17:10900 EU lobby server hosted in Frankfurt, Germany
>
> 64.25.35.100:6600 Shared NA/EU Authentication Server hosted in Dallas, Texas
>
> 64.25.35.105 EU Sandbox Profile server hosted in Dallas, Texas
>
> 64.25.35.118 EU Sandbox Image server host in Dallas, Texas
>
> 64.25.35.106 EU Market server hosted in Dallas, Texas